# Concatenation of 2 lists

Tags: haskell

I have list type defined as
`data List a = Empty | Entry a (List a)`

I need to write a function with signature
`appendList :: List a -> List a -> List a`

Looks like recursion might be useful here but I have no idea on how to use it

Comment: Yes, you need recursion. Try writing the result of `appendList Empty l` (don't overthink it!), then that for `appendList (Entry a l1) l2` in terms of `appendList l1 l2`.

Comment: I think I understood, thanks a lot !  

`appendList (Entry a Empty) l2 = Entry a l2`  
`appendList (Entry a l1) l2 = Entry a (appendList l1 l2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59460734/concatenation-of-2-lists#comment105102696_59460734) you solved most of the problem yourself.

What might help (in the future) is to exhaustively take a look at all the combinations of the data constructors. Since there are here two parameters, and each such `List a` has two data constructors, we thus can write as skeleton:

```
appendList :: List a -> List a -> List a
appendList Empty Empty = …
appendList Empty (Entry x xs) = …
appendList (Entry x xs) Empty = …
appendList (Entry x xs) (Entry y ys) = …
```

Now we can reason over these cases. If both lists are `Empty`, then the result is an `Empty` list as well. If the first list is `Empty`, and the second is non-empty, then we return the second list. If the first list is non-empty, and the second list is empty, then we return the first list. Finally if both lists are non-empty, we make a list that will yield the first item of the first list, and recurse on the tail of the first list, and the second list.

So we can implement this with:

```
appendList :: List a -> List a -> List a
appendList Empty Empty = Empty
appendList Empty (Entry x xs) = (Entry x xs)
appendList (Entry x xs) Empty = (Entry x xs)
appendList (Entry x xs) (Entry y ys) = (Entry x (appendList xs (Entry y ys)))
```

We can now compress these clauses. For example the firt two clauses can be resolved by simply returning the second list. The third and fourth clause can be compressed to `Entry x (AppendList xs ya)` where `ya` is the second parameter:

```
appendList :: List a -> List a -> List a
appendList Empty ya = ya
appendList (Entry x xs) ya = (Entry x (appendList xs ya))
```

or we can make this more compact with:

```
appendList :: List a -> List a -> List a
appendList Empty = id
appendList (Entry x xs) = Entry x . appendList xs
```